# CanvasJS Chart Width Bug Until Window is Resized

Tags: javascript, html, charts, carousel, canvasjs

I've seen other people with this issue, but none that ended with a resolution. I'm building an array of charts to cycle through a carousel, and as far as the elements tab on the Chrome debugger is concerned, all widths are the same/correct. The issue is that until the window is resized, whether that be by pulling up the debugger or going in/out of fullscreen, only the active carousel item is actually 100% width.

[Squished Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiGfm.png)

[JavaScript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGnVA.png)

[Html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXg9o.png)

Here is my code for resizing the width of the charts getting called on a window resize event. I attempted to add it to the document ready event, but this doesn't work. Something about the styles not loading in time. Honestly I'm stuck, and can't even find a hack to get past this.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < charts.length; i++) {
                charts[i].options.width = $('.carousel').width();
                charts[i].options.height = $('.carousel').height();
                charts[i].render();
            }
        })
```

I also tried adding a timeout to drawing the chart - still squishy chart.

`setTimeout(GetDriverCount('bgxp'), 1500);`

Here is my desired result (which occurs successfully after a resize event)

[Chart 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFnHj.png)
[Squished Chart After Resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvC98.png)

Comment: you need to wait until the chart is shown in the carousel before drawing for the first time, you can use the `slid.bs.carousel` event

Comment: How would I go about doing this? I tried testing with an alert, but wasn't able to trigger the event.

Answer (score 0):

VICTORY!! Here are the additions I made to end up with my desired result:

After initializing the carousel interval on document ready, I added the cycle event followed by the slide.bs.carousel event to set the height and width of my charts.

Once that was complete, I drew my charts. I also left the height and width assignments on the window resize event as this was still an issue.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#chart-carousel').carousel({
                interval: 4500
            });
            $('#chart-carousel').carousel('cycle');

            $('#chart-carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < charts.length; i++) {
                    charts[i].options.width = $('.carousel').width();
                    charts[i].options.height = $('.carousel').height();
                    charts[i].render();
                } 
            })

            GetDriverCount($('#companyKpi').val());
        })
```